# Seeking tool to graphically show (header) file dependancies in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I know that header guards avoid (most) trouble; call me @n@l if you like, but I just don't like a sloppy header-file tree.

If I draw on paper a box for each header file and connect them by lines representing #include, I like to see a neat hierarchy.  But what I usually see is a complex web.

Maybe I *am* @n@l, but to me that tangled web represents sloppy-thinking and I would like to induce order by reorganizing the #include hierarchy.

Does anyone know of a tool which will let me vizualize the #include hierarchy? Preferably a free tool.

(and, yes, I know that I "could probably do it with graphviz dot", but that is not an answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doxygen can do this for you if you use it along with the dot tool.

Here is an example: http://www.neuraladvance.com/json-c/html/json_8h.html

Comment: Doxygen can also print a neat hierarchy diagram representing all dependencies for C, C++, Python, Java, etc.

Comment: hmm, why didn't I think about Doxygen?    

Simon, can it do that for the whole project, or just on aper-file basis?   

I really want it for the whole project. You don't really see the complexity on a single file.

Comment: @Mawg - I'm not sure to be honest. I've never had the need for a full dependency graph. I'm pretty sure that it would be easy to do although you might have to do a bit delving. After all Doxygen already has everything you need you might just have to do the stitching together manually.

Comment: Yep, DoxyGen does it!  Thanks.

Comment: @Mawg - please tell us how! You may want to put that in an answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496644/using-doxygen-to-create-through-graphvizs-dot-a-graphical-representation-of-th

Answer (score 4):

You could try [cinclude2dot](http://flourish.org/cinclude2dot/)

Comment: At first glance, it looks perfect, thanks! I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: This is the kind of tool that made Unix great.  +1