# Using doxygen to create (through graphviz's dot) a graphical representation of the entire program

Tags: doxygen, graphviz, dot

A stack overflow thread (found through google of course) directed me to use doxygen to auto-create documentation (originally because I inherited a code base that was to be diagrammed, and I got tired of doing it by hand through Dia Diagram Editor).

Now doxygen has turned out to be really quite useful. However there is one thing I still can't seem to make it do: generate an include (or call) diagram for the entire code base. It'll generate an include hierarchy for a single file, or a call diagram for a single function, but I want to see the whole thing (it's not a very large code base :D ).

Anyone happen to know?

P.S. this in C, but I doubt it matters.

Answer (score 3):

Whole-program static analysis is really beyond the scope of Doxygen, I feel.

However, the question ['Tools to get a pictorial function call graph of code'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/517589/104370) asks for much the same thing, and the answers refer to a number of different tools that sound very promising.